# How to get gender and birthday information of a google sign in user using People API,Oauth 2 API in Android?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-people-api

All the answers on SO looks outdated and com.google.android.gms.plus.People is also deprecated which Google used in People API documentation. Attaching the code below

```
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();


    String clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    String clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

    String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";


    String authorizationUrl = new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl(clientId,
                                                                redirectUrl,
                                                                Arrays.asList(scope))
        .build();

    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();

    GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
        httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();


    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
        .build()
        .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

    People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .build();
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the authenticated user's profile by doing a get on "people/me" as in the example in https://developers.google.com/people/v1/requests#get-the-users-profile

You'll need these permissions:
 - profile - (Let's you use "people/me" to get the authenticated user)
 - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read  - (to get the user's birthday)

Right now for gender you will only get it if it's public. There's no scope to get private gender.